# SQL Identitfy records where all child values are given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to identify all records where all of the parent's child records are given as I then need to wrap these up to the parent level. For example, if you imagine two tables:

`tblParentChild`:

```
Id       Code       ParentCode
-------------------------------
1        B001       
2        P001   
3        B002       B001       
4        B003       B001
5        P002       P001
6        P003       P001
7        P004       P001
```

`tblData`:

```
Header Id   Code
-------------------
1           P002
2           B002
2           B003
3           P003
3           P004
4           P002    
4           P003
4           P004
```

So in this example I would want to return headers 2 and 4 as these have all of the child records present. I have been doing this concatenating the child records in both tables and comparing the results (P002;P003;P004) but I’m sure there must be a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Can we see your code? What is the result you are getting and what is the result you are expecting? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear but do you have parents and children in tblData. Then you have tblParentChild to handle a many to many relationship? Also, you should consider not "tbling" your objects. The prefixes on objects provide no real benefit and they make your code much more difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of ugly and probably performs like garbage, but I think this would work:

```
; WITH parentCTE (ParentCode, PCCount) AS
    (SELECT ParentCode, PCCount = count(*) 
     FROM #tblParentChild 
     WHERE ParentCode IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY ParentCode)
SELECT HeaderID
FROM #tblData d
INNER JOIN #tblParentChild pc ON pc.Code = d.Code
GROUP BY pc.ParentCode, d.HeaderID
HAVING count(pc.Code) = (SELECT PCCount FROM parentCTE WHERE ParentCode = pc.ParentCode)
```